# XSSFWorkbook stays in memory

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache pio version 3.14 to export some data to excel. The problem is that it uses a lot of memory. With VisualVM i noticed that data in oldgen shoots up from ~80M to ~400M for a 800K export file and it stays there. If i repeat the operation over and over it keeps growing. It seems XSSFWorkbook is never garbage collected and it holds the references for all the cells/sheets from the excel file.
I tried using SXSSFWorkbook but the memory usage is similar.
Is there a way to reduce memory usage? Or how can i dispose XSSFWorkbook. I tried closing the workbook and making the reference to it null, but this does not help

Comment: if its expensive, do it you yourself.

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet please ?

Answer (score 0):

Today I saw the same problem in our application. The workbook with all the cells lands in the old generation and is never deleted. To analyze the problem I created an application which creates a workbook with 10 rows where each row has 10 cells.

[image: XSSFWorkbook in Main]

Then I tried to move the code into a separate thread.

[image: XSSFWorkbook in Runnable]

Still some objects remain in the memory but the workbook, the sheet, the rows and cells are gone. Here is a **simplified** code sample to show how I tested it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Workbook workbook = null;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

            try {
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
                Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
                Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
                cell.setCellValue("test");
                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/workbook.xlsx"));
                workbook.write(fileOutputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (workbook != null) {
                    try {
                        workbook.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();

    // Infinite loop to monitor with visualvm
    for(;;);
}
```

Comment: Can you add some sample code to help explain what this looks like?